# Error while calling restTemplate.exchange method

Tags: java, rest

```
StringBuilder driverIds = new StringBuilder();
for (Driver driver : driverList) {
     driverIds.append(driver.getDriverId()).append(STRING_SEPARATOR_COMMA);
}
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity(requestHeader);
UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = constructUriForGetDriverOrContractList (endpointContractService,PATH_SEGMENT_CONTRACT,serviceRequestContext, clientId, driverIds.toString()); return Arrays.asList(Objects.requireNonNull(restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET,entity, Contract[].class).getBody()));
```

On return statement code getting failed bcoz of long list of driver id's (like 1500 ids) converting it to comma separated string, which I think in get call its failing. Any idea how to handle this